# Transconductance in mosfets

Tags: mosfet

What exactly does it mean when we say 'increase the transconductance of a mosfet'? What is the advantage of having a high transconductance mosfet?

Answer (score 1):

A MOSFET is a transconductance device in that an input voltage controls an output current or, in terms of gain, current out / voltage in. Current/voltage is conductance and the word "trans" is placed in front of the word "conductance" to imply the main operating parameter of such a device.

So a device with more transconductance means that it produces a bigger change in output current for a change in input voltage. Not always desirable of course but pretty useful in a lot of applications.

Comment: High transconductance means fewer stages of gain, or quicker switching (speed being gm/C).

Comment: @analogsystemsrf Are you saying that a **higher** transconductance rating on the datasheet corresponds with **lower** "gain"?